# In Hadoop, where can i change default url ports 50070 and 50030 for namenode and jobtracker webpages

Tags: hadoop, nosql, mapreduce, hbase, elastic-map-reduce

There must be a way to change the ports 50070 and 50030 so that the following urls display the clustr statuses on the ports i pick

```
NameNode - http://localhost:50070/
JobTracker - http://localhost:50030/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your choice of ports by setting properties `dfs.http.address` for Namenode and `mapred.job.tracker.http.address` for Jobtracker in conf/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.http.address</name>
        <value>50070</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
        <value>50030</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: But in the properties how do i mention interms of syntax? For example, the server IP and port: 10.12.65.160:7000     Do i put http before and how to make the entry? Please help, Im a noob in this

Comment: also, I only have 2 ports available (:7000, :7199) due to our strict firewall team. How can i get access to view all the URLS?

Comment: I updated the answer with the syntax to use.  It's between you and your firewall team to come up with two ports that you can use.

Comment: The urls are not working. Do i need apache server or something?

Answer (score 5):

This question is old but probably worth pointing out the namenode port is set via dfs.namenode.http-address in conf/hdfs-site.xml.

```
<property>
         <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
                          <value>0.0.0.0:50020</value>
</property>
```

I was misled by the other answers for this question so hopefully this helps someone else. At least this is how it is for hadoop 2.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

The default Hadoop ports are as follows:

```
Daemon                   Default Port  Configuration Parameter
-----------------------  ------------ ----------------------------------
Namenode                 50070        dfs.http.address
Datanodes                50075        dfs.datanode.http.address
Secondarynamenode        50090        dfs.secondary.http.address
Backup/Checkpoint node?  50105        dfs.backup.http.address
Jobracker                50030        mapred.job.tracker.http.address
Tasktrackers             50060        mapred.task.tracker.http.address
```

If we wish to change any port then add corresponding in conf/core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

To look at the ports what all are running we can get it through

netstat -plten | grep java