# Jetty server in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, jetty

I'm using Hadoop single node cluster.I want to change the hadoop default running port 50070 to any other port in Jetty Server.help me to sort this out

Comment: Check if this SO link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422770/in-hadoop-where-can-i-change-default-url-ports-50070-and-50030-for-namenode-and & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855232/default-namenode-port-of-hdfs-is-50070-but-i-have-come-across-at-some-places-802

Comment: I understand now Thank you